# How to print id of user whose profile I visit rather than id of  logged in user?

Tags: users

I would like to print the id of the user on his profile page? How can I do it in Drupal 7. So far I could only print logged in user id..Any advice appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print id of user whose profile I visit rather than id of  logged in user?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/how-to-print-id-of-user-whose-profile-i-visit-rather-than-id-of-logged-in-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) allows you to get a user/node/.. object based of the current request URL.

To get the account object, you can do this:

```
if ($account = menu_get_object('user')) {
  print $account->uid;
}
```

Comment: what happens when you're using profile2 (d7) and you don't have user/xx in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function. You can add a condition to test if the page is the user page. It would be appropriate to place this in the template.php file using HOOK_preprocess function.

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) {
  $MY_USER_PAGE_ID = arg(1);
}
```