# How to print id of user whose profile I visit rather than id of  logged in user?

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print id of user whose profile I visit rather than id of  logged in user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5453/how-to-print-id-of-user-whose-profile-i-visit-rather-than-id-of-logged-in-user)

I would like to print the id of the user on his profile page? How can I do it in Drupal 7. So far I could only print logged in user id..Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`hook_user_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7). I have small module named nova to customise various aspects of drupal.  So if I use the following function in my module, I get the title "Id of the Member" and then the output of uid.

```
function nova_user_view($account) {
  $account->content['myid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('Id of the Member'),
    '#markup' => $account->uid,
  );
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you or if you need more explanation.

Comment: When building the profile page, Drupal calls all hook_user_view() implementations. Each one can add its own _item_ to display on the profile page as element of the $account->content array. $account is actually the user object for the viewed profile. In most Drupal code, to avoid confusion, the convention is to use $user for the current currently logged-in user and $account for other any other user.

Answer (score 5):

If you add this to the user-profile.tpl.php template, it will show the UID of user account being viewed.

```
<?php echo $account->uid;?>
```