# Displaying uid on user/x/ and user/x/edit page

Tags: 7, users

I want to display the **uid** (read-only) of the user on both the **user/x** and **user/x/edit** page.

By using the function below I managed to show the **uid** on the **user/x/edit** page.

```
function my_module_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (arg(0) == 'user') {
        $form['uid_read_only'] = array(
            '#markup' => 'User id : ' . '<b>' . arg(1) . '</b>',
            '#weight' => -500,
            '#disabled' => TRUE,
        );
    }
}
```

How do I show the uid on the **user/x** page (view state)?

Comment: Your code will display the `uid` of the currently logged in user. This is only the same as `x` if the user edits his own account. If I edit the account of a different user, my `uid` will still be displayed instead of the `uid` of the user whose account I edit. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: You're right, thanks for noticing. I think just grabbing the arg(1) is sufficient, agree?

Comment: Yes, `arg(1)` is sufficient in your case. The alternative would be to call [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), passing `'user'` as `$type` and `1` as `$position`. This gives you the user object associated with the URL. But I do not see the benefits of this method.

Comment: ok, to close it off...is it correct when I'm saying that the check I'm performing if (arg(0) == 'user') is not really necessary because this function form_user_profile_form_alter will always and only be executed on a page with arg(0) as user?

Comment: Taking only the Drupal core into account, you are correct: the check for `arg(0) == 'user'` is not necessary. Contrib modules might see this differently. I usually make a clear distinction between form builder functions (that don't make any assumption about why they were called) and page callbacks (that accept arguments from the URL). E.g. in my opinion, it's a mistake that the form builder function [user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login/7) issues a [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [hook_user_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7) to show the **uid** on the **user/x** page.

Comment: Thanks, got it. For code example people can look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5484/8606

Answer (score 0):

Start by copying drupal theme user-profile.tpl.php into your theme, make sure to keep the name as user-profile.tpl.php.

open the file and edit it the way you want, I usually use this to get the uid

```
global $user
$uid = $user->uid;
```

then maybe you want to do something like:

```
print $user->uid;
```

Dont forget to clear your cache.